# Does TypeORM work with AWS Aurora Serverless?

Tags: typeorm, aws-aurora-serverless

Does TypeORM work with AWS Aurora Serverless, specifically the Postgres compatible version?

Answer (score 4):

As of Dec. 2019, it doesn't - we've been looking for the same thing in the past couple of weeks.

There is a driver package called [typeorm-aurora-data-api-driver](https://github.com/ArsenyYankovsky/typeorm-aurora-data-api-driver) which you can use in combination with TypeORM, but according to its author ([source](https://github.com/ArsenyYankovsky/typeorm-aurora-data-api-driver/issues/22#issuecomment-547112977)), it hasn't been tested with the PostgreSQL flavor of Aurora Serverless and it would require additional work in TypeORM to support it.

Note that this "driver" package relies on the [data-api-client](https://github.com/jeremydaly/data-api-client) package to connect to the Aurora Serverless cluster.

**Edit**

The driver package has been updated to work with Postgres in recent releases.